# Circle draw algorithm explanation

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, geometry

Given the following circle drawing algorithm (variation of Bresenham) :

```
public static void
drawCircle(Graphics g, MyPoint center, MyPoint point)
{
    // calculate radius of circle
    final int radius = (int)(Math.sqrt((point.x()-center.x())*(point.x()-center.x())+(point.y()-center.y())*(point.y()-center.y())));

    int x = 0, y = radius, u = 0, v = 2 * radius - 1, E = 0;
    while (x < y)
    {
        drawPixel(g, new MyPoint(center.x() + x, center.y() + y)); // NNE
        drawPixel(g, new MyPoint(center.x() + y, center.y() - x)); // ESE
        drawPixel(g, new MyPoint(center.x() - x, center.y() - y)); // SSW
        drawPixel(g, new MyPoint(center.x() - y, center.y() + x)); // WNW
        ++x;
        E += u;
        u += 2;
        if (v < 2 * E){
            y--; E -= v; v -= 2;
        }
        if (x > y) break;
        drawPixel(g, new MyPoint(center.x() + y, center.y() + x)); // ENE
        drawPixel(g, new MyPoint(center.x() + x, center.y() - y)); // SSE
        drawPixel(g, new MyPoint(center.x() - y, center.y() - x)); // WSW
        drawPixel(g, new MyPoint(center.x() - x, center.y() + y)); // NNW

    }
}
```

I don't seem to understand why it works. I do understand that it draws a pixel at each octant because the circle is symmetric but I don't get  what the variables u, v and e stand for..? e stands for the error I suppose but when does it change? and why?

help will be appreciated! thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and/or pencil and paper?

Comment: I actually did. Noticed how it works and why a circle is achieved. but can't really understand why it is true, and why v is initialized to be 2 * r - 1, etc.

Comment: It looks like `u == 2*x` at all times, so perhaps someone thought that it would be more efficient to keep a separate `u` instead of just saying `E += 2 * x` (before incrementing `x`).  This could conceivably be slightly more efficient if the algorithm is written in assembly language on some processors, although it's hard to imagine, since I don't recall ever seeing a processor without at least a "shift left 1 bit" instruction.

Comment: @ajb Having two completely independent variables and incrementing them independently can be more efficient than deriving one from the other; making them completely independent gives a CPU with out-of-order excution capability better opportunities to do so, and even with in-order execution, multiple issue pipelines can execute independent instructions (without register or memory conflicts) in paralell. But as always that an extremely low level optimization and it depends heavily on the CPU one is optimizing for.

Comment: @Durandal OK, that makes sense, and I can see how this might work on TI c6x DSP's.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help you some:

http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/bresenham.html

Answer (score 0):

Its always hard to reverse-engineer optimized algorithms, because the underlying invariants are often obscured or totally omitted in the final code.

In that case take a look behind the scenes, for example Wikipedia has a detailed explanation of the math used:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_circle_algorithm